# jqxgrid selectionmode checkbox , check already selected checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, selected, checked, jqxgrid

I am using similar kind of jqxgrid shown in below link.
How can we show already selected check boxes ?
Let say I have to show countries in jqxgrid, already i have choosen 2 countries earlier.
Now I want to shown already selected checkboxes  as checked and allow user to do more selection of countries.
Please help

Thx

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using selectrow method of jqxGrid. You need to pass a row index when you call the method. By doing that, you will select a row and the checkbox will be checked.

Comment: Selectrow will select only one row so I went with selectedrowindexes and pass array.
It's working but the selection is shown when we slide grid
I even tried to pass same array while creating grid at this time can't setcontent

Comment: Have you tried calling the Grid's refresh method after setting selectedrowindexes?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I iterate array and Selectrow and it's working 
Thanks a lot